# Modify field definition using scheduled Apex job

Tags: custom-field, scheduled-apex, automation

In the current data model of my org, there is a Master-Detail relationship between Account (Master) and Revenue (Detail).  I have 12 custom fields on Revenue (January, February, ..., November, December), each storing the revenue made for the month.  Multiple Revenue records could exist for the same month for different products (a custom field of Revenue).

There are then 3 Roll-up Summary fields on Account (LM, L2M, L3M) to store the Account's total revenue for all products for last month, 2nd last month, and 3rd last month, respectively.  These LM, L2M and L3M fields are essentially used for reporting purposes.

Each month, manual update of the field definition of LM, L2M and L3M is required to increment the Field to Aggregate value (e.g. from January to February when March comes).  I'm wondering if, without changing the current data model, there is a way I could manipulate the definition of the Roll-up Summary fields so this update can happen automatically (by using an Apex scheduled job perhaps).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: All things being equal, you'd probably be better off creating a batch job to do this for you - it would be easier to code and far less error-prone.

Comment: Why not 12 RSF RSF01, RSF02, ..RSF12 on Account that roll up Jan, Feb, ...Dec. Then three formula fields on Account - LM, L2M, and L3M that use the value of TODAY to select from the appropriate RSFxx fields. You can get SFDC Admin to increase your RSF count from 10 to 10+  on Account. n.b. You didn't define what you do at year end

Comment: On further thought, you need to define how you handle the rollup in January as it need's last year's Dec, Nov, and Oct values. As an Account can have revenue over more than one year, you have a more complex filter to choose which rows to rollup

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating field definitions has to be done via the Metadata API which is not directly accessible via Apex code.  Another approach would be to use the Metadata API directly via either the [forcecli](https://github.com/heroku/force) or the [Force.com Ant Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool).

You would need to script the changes to the field definitions in the Account.object file and then deploy the file to your org.  Since it's just a script (either shell or ant), you can schedule it from any computer to run monthly (i.e. via cron).

I'd recommend building a package.xml file that only lists the 3 custom fields on Account you want to edit.  Use that file in the retrieve call as the manifest for what to retrieve.  This way, the Account.object you'd get from your org would only have those 3 custom fields.  Then, have your script make the modifications to Account.object and deploy.

Comment: N.b. the metadata API may be accessed via Apex - see apex wrapper for Metadata API here: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi - it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metadata API and try to program the dynamic creation of the fields in your batch class: http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/

However, this is not the right path to follow and the metadata API is not meant to be used for the purpose that you've described. The need to dynamically modify the field definition in order to meet the reporting requirements is an indication that your data model is not properly defined. I suggest that you review your data model and configure it correctly so that you will be able to generate the needed reports.